# Exception in thread error when updating my dict containing a list of messages in flask-socketio

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cs50, flask-socketio

I am building a basic chat application for cs50 project2.

I have a dict storing all of my messages with the users name, time, and message, and the values of message contents are in a list.

Right now I am using sessions to store each of the messages in its own channel, but when I post a message into the chatroom, I get the traceback...

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 682, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 711, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 282, in _handler
    return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 713, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "/Users/aparep7474/Desktop/project2/application.py", line 103, in post
    if len(messages_created[session['current_channel']]) > 100:
KeyError: 'Hello'
```

When the user clicks the post button it takes the value of the input field, and then it emits a the submit post function. This is then received by my flask app where it appends the info to the dict and emits the message to be dynamically shown to the user.

My Flask code:

Most of the important code is at the end

```
import os, requests

from flask import Flask, session, redirect, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from helpers import login_required

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "4301"
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')

users_online = []

channels_created = []

messages_created = {}


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():

    if session.get("current_channel") is None:
        return redirect("/create_channel")

    else:
        return redirect("/channels/" + session.get("current_channel"))


@app.route("/log_in", methods=['GET','POST'])
def log_in():

    username = request.form.get("username")

    if request.method == "POST":

        if len(username) == 0:
            return render_template("error.html", message="username can't be empty.")

        if username in users_online:
            return render_template("error.html", message="that username already exists.")

        users_online.append(username)

        session['username'] = username

        session.permanent = True

        return redirect("/create_channel")

    else:
        return render_template("log_in.html")


@app.route("/log_out", methods=['GET','POST'])
def log_out():

    try:
        users_online.remove(session['username'])
    except ValueError:
        pass

    session.clear()

    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/create_channel", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def create_channel():

    session.pop("current_channel", None)

    new_channel = request.form.get("channel")

    if request.method == "POST":

        if new_channel in channels_created:
            return render_template("error.html", message="that channel already exists.")

        channels_created.append(new_channel)

        return redirect("/channels/" + new_channel)

    else:
        return render_template("create_channel.html", channels=channels_created)


@app.route("/channels/<channel>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def channel_name(channel):

    session['current_channel'] = channel

    session.permanent = True

    return render_template("channel.html", channels=channels_created)


@socketio.on("submit post")
def post(data):

    if len(messages_created[session['current_channel']]) > 100:
        messages_created[session['current_channel']].pop(0)

    messages_created[session['current_channel']].append([session.get("username"), data["message"], datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")])

    message = data["message"]

    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

    emit("announce post", {"message": message, "time": time, "username": session.get("username")}, room=room, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

My HTML Code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  {{ session.current_channel }}
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
  <style>
    #box {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='channel.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 class="text-center">{{ session.current_channel }}</h1>
  <body>
    <div id="box">
      {% if messages_created %}
        {% for message in messages_created %}
          <ul>
            <li><strong> {{ message[0] }} </strong> : {{ message[1] }} <small class="float-right"> {{ message[2] }} </small></li>
          </ul>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <ul id="posts">
        </ul>
      </div>
    <hr>
    <form id="form">
      <input id="message" autofocus autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Your Post Here" style="height: 40px;width: 800px;" class="mt-3">
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Post</button>
    </form>
  </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Layout.html just contains a nav bar that just contains a dropdown with the channels and a logout button.

Finally my JS Code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = () => {
      const message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
      socket.emit('submit post', {'message': message});
      document.querySelector("#message").value = '';
      return false;
    };
  });

  socket.on('announce post', data => {
    console.log('received');
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `<strong> ${data.username} </strong> : ${data.message} <small class="float-right"> ${data.time} </small>`;
    document.querySelector('#posts').append(li);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you change the current channel you should initialize `messages_created[session['current_channel']]` to an empty list.

Comment: How do I initialize the empty list if it is created using a session? Sorry I'm really new to all of this python list stuff

Comment: Just assign an empty list (i.e. `[]`) to the current channel entry in your session.

Comment: Thank you so much for you're help. When I create the new channel I also create a list from where the channel was created.