# li tag is not generating values with socketio using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am having difficulty to generate `li` tag with a javascript socket when I submit values to a text field and send ***nothing*** returned back and shown ***no error**. The `js` rendered correctly.The application integrated with python/flask, javascript, and HTML to give the desired output.

***The desired output***

- it should take text input and generate to the user

**What I tried**

```
        document.querySelector('#frm').onsubmit = () => {
                const message = document.querySelector('#txtMessage').value;
                socket.emit('submit chat', { 'message': message });
            };
    });
```

Take a look at the following code snippet from flask, javascript and HTML

**index.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure textarea (listening)
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // textarea should emit an  event
        document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
                const message = document.querySelector('#txtMessage').value;
                socket.emit('talk', { 'message': message });
            };
    });

    // When a new announce announced, add to the unordered list (trigger)
    socket.on('announce', data => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = `Eyasu Twitt: ${data.message}`;
        document.querySelector('#messages').append(li);
    });
});
```

**from app.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketPlug.on("talk")
def chat(data):
    message = data["message"]
    emit("announce chat", {"message": message}, broadcast=True)
```

**from index.html**

```
        <ul id="messages">
        </ul>
        <hr>
    <form id="frm">
        <textarea id="txtMessage" type="text"></textarea>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page reloads on submit, that is why your page doesn't respond because it doesn't store it in server storage. To stop it from reloading you can add the `type="button"` to the button and add these two lines to the end of your js emit...

```
document.querySelector("#txtMessage").value = '';
return false;
```

Also I don't think your parenthesis are aligned in your js code.

For reference look at my code at [Exception in thread error when updating my dict containing a list of messages in flask-socketio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431738/exception-in-thread-error-when-updating-my-dict-containing-a-list-of-messages-in)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can I add a fancy `li` tag where I found from bootstrap `li design`?

Comment: After you append the li element add the following code...```v.className += "yourclassname";``` and add ```var v = document.querySelector("li");```. I found this code on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-adding-a-class-name-to-the-element/